# How to grant Azure CLI graph api permissions

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api, azure-cli

As far as I understand the azcli doesn't have an app registration in AAD, and now that it's possible to make rest calls from the azcli, how does one grant permissions that are required for certain calls?

```
$ az rest --method get --url https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/privilegedAccess/azureResources/roleAssignments?$filter=subjectId+eq+'xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxx-xxxxxxxx'
Unauthorized({
  "error": {
    "code": "UnknownError",
    "message": "{\"errorCode\":\"PermissionScopeNotGranted\",\"message\":\"Authorization failed due to missing permission scope PrivilegedAccess.Read.AzureResources,PrivilegedAccess.ReadWrite.AzureResources.\",\"target\":null,\"details\":null,\"innerError\":null,\"instanceAnnotations\":[],\"typeAnnotation\":null}",
    "innerError": {
      "date": "2021-02-18T09:31:46",
      "request-id": "989c1555-aa84-45a7-8fd9-e168531fcf88",
      "client-request-id": "989c1555-aa84-45a7-8fd9-e168531fcf88"
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Does the below answer help?

Comment: No, it doesn't.

Comment: But, this feature is not possible to achieve in beta version. Can I know what else you are expecting?

Comment: I don't believe it's not possible because of beta version. Our MSFT architect is discussing with the product team, will let you know the result.

Nevetheless, looks like the final solution would be if microsoft implements PIM commands into azcli, since the rest API method only seems possible (at least for now) with a SP, which I want to avoid

Comment: Sure, keep this thread updated with your findings.

Answer (score 0):

As [Microsoft Graph REST API v1.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/overview?view=graph-rest-1.0) is now GA, we can call it directly with `az rest` to achieve the same effect as `az ad` commands, including all latest features from Microsoft Graph. It can automatically authenticate to Microsoft Graph.

**And, for this you will have to use `v1.0` version of the API: `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0`** Using this, it should work.

*Check out this [GitHub Issue #12946](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/12946) about the same for more details.*

Comment: Thanks, however the API for privilegedAccess is only avaialble in beta, nevertheless it's still under the graph API, so should not matter here.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/privilegedaccess?view=graph-rest-beta

Comment: Then, it is not supported to use `az rest` for `privilegedAccess ` for now, because calling Graph API using `az rest` is available only for version `1.0`. You can verify this for other APIs like `GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{id|userPrincipalName}/manager`